# Maya python API: How to make float array attribute editable in the channel box/attribute editor?

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

I'm writing a custom node and I need an array of floats. I noticed that if I create an array attribute with `om.MFnNumericData.k3Float` type, then I can add new elements and edit the values in the attribute editor:[image]

But if I change the type to `om.MFnNumericData.kFloat`, I can no longer do that:[image]

Is this expected behaviour? What should I do to have the float array attribute editable?